# I need to add the selected item of a combo box to the end of selected item in the list box

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

This is the data in the list box, from a database

```
  Johnie Black
  Sarah Smith
  Carol Willis
  Maggie Dubois
```

This is the data in the combo Box

```
  (M)
  (F)
```

I want to select a name in the listbox then when I proceed to select the gender from the comboBox the value I select must be added to the end of the name that is selected

example.

Carol Willis(F)

This is what I have tried:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {                                                                                this.namesTableAdapter.Fill(this.namesDataSet.names);
    comboBox1.Items.Add("(M)");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("(F)");
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
} 
//The code above loads the items into the comboBox 
//For the lisbox I connected to the database using the option "Use Data Bound Items"
```

Any form of help will be appreciated

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried comboBox.SelectedValue = listBox1.SelectedValue

Comment: I have also tried using the SelectedIndexChanged event but nothing has worked

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

This should point you into the right direction:

```
public ListBox lbNames = new ListBox();
public ComboBox cbxGender = new ComboBox();

// combobox selected index changed event
private void cbxGender_SelectedIndex_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if there are selected items
    if(lbNames.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && cbxGender.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        // replace previous added gender
        Regex.Replace(lbNames.SelectedItem.ToString(), @".+(\([MF]\))", "");
        // append new gender
        lbNames.Items[lbNames.SelectedIndex] = lbNames.SelectedItem.ToString() + cbxGender.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Wasnt tested, just a hint.

Comment: Thank You , will try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank You , will try it out

Comment: This one would append the gender over and over again if you click multiple times. Like `Carol Willis(F)(F)(F)(F)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedItems)
        {
            if (comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
                item.Text += " " + comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to double click/add the "SelectedIndexChanged" event in the properties of your ComboBox on form.

Comment: This one would append the gender over and over again if you click multiple times. Like `Carol Willis(F)(F)(F)(F)`.